# Count the number of null values into an Oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to count the number of null values of all the columns in a table in Oracle.

For instance, I execute the following statements to create a table TEST and insert data.

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST
 (  A VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    B VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    C VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  );
Insert into TEST (A) values ('a');
Insert into TEST (B) values ('b');
Insert into TEST (C) values ('c');
```

Now, I write the following code to compute the number of null values in the table TEST:

```
declare 
cnt number :=0;
temp number :=0;
begin
  for r in ( select column_name, data_type
             from    user_tab_columns 
             where table_name = upper('test')
             order by column_id )
  loop
      if r.data_type <> 'NOT NULL' then
         select count(*) into temp FROM TEST where r.column_name IS NULL;
         cnt := cnt + temp;
      END IF;
  end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total: '||cnt);
end;
/
```

It returns 0, when the expected value is 6.

Where is the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in a single column or all columns? `Select sum(case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end + ....) as NullValues from table`

Comment: Hi xQbert, in all columns!

Comment: You cannot use the name of a column as a parameter in plain SQL queries. In order to do so, you can perform a dynamic SQL.  https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Comment: If you can solve an issue with plain sql you should favor this way over procedural code.

Comment: @jackattack your proposed solution with plain SQL does not respond my question. I need a total number of null value. That is something that, 
sum(col1_nulls, col2_nulls, ...., colN_nulls);

Comment: See update on my comment

Comment: Thank you @jackattack, but in your solution I need to know all information about the table: table name and the columns names. See my answer!

Comment: did last update answer your question?

Comment: Are the number of columns always known in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Lord Peter :

The below PL/SQL script works

```
declare 
cnt number :=0;
temp number :=0;
begin
  for r in ( select column_name, nullable
             from    user_tab_columns 
             where table_name = upper('test')
             order by column_id )
  loop
      if r.nullable = 'Y' then
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM test where '|| r.column_name ||' IS NULL' into temp ;
         cnt := cnt + temp;
      END IF;
  end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total: '||cnt);
end;
/
```

The table name ***test*** may be replaced the name of table of your interest.

I hope this solution is useful!

Comment: `NOT NULL` is not a data type. And you should try to do this in one pass rather than scanning the table once for each column.

Comment: Thanks @William Robertson, you're right. I just fixed the code.

Comment: Great, that's an improvement. It's still full-scanning the table once per non-mandatory column, though.

Answer (score 2):

### Counting NULLs for each column

In order to count NULL values for **all columns** of a table *T* you could run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(col1) col1_nulls
     , COUNT(*) - COUNT(col2) col2_nulls
     ,..
     , COUNT(*) - COUNT(colN) colN_nulls
     , COUNT(*) total_rows
FROM   T
/
```

Where *col1, col2, .., colN* should be replaced with actual names of columns of *T* table.

Aggregate functions -like `COUNT()`- ignore NULL values, so `COUNT(*) - COUNT(col)` will give you how many nulls for each column.

### Summarize all NULLs of a table

If you want to know how many fields are NULL, I mean every NULL of every record you can

```
WITH d as (    
    SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(col1) col1_nulls
         , COUNT(*) - COUNT(col2) col2_nulls
         ,..
         , COUNT(*) - COUNT(colN) colN_nulls
         , COUNT(*) total_rows
    FROM   T
) SELECT col1_nulls + col1_nulls +..+ colN_null
  FROM d 
/
```

### Summarize all NULLs of a table (using Oracle dictionary tables)

Following is an improvement in which you need to now nothing but table name and it is very easy to code a function based on it

```
DECLARE
  T    VARCHAR2(64) := '<YOUR TABLE NAME>';
  expr VARCHAR2(32767);
  q    INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'SELECT /*+FULL(T) PARALLEL(T)*/' || COUNT(*) || ' * COUNT(*) OVER () - ' || LISTAGG('COUNT(' || COLUMN_NAME || ')', ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) || ' FROM ' || T
  INTO   expr
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = T;

  -- This line is for debugging purposes only
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(expr);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE expr INTO q;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q);
END;
/
```

Due to calculation implies a full table scan, code produced in *expr* variable was optimized for parallel running.

### User defined function *null_fields*

Function version, also includes an optional parameter  to be able to run on other schemas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION null_fields(table_name IN VARCHAR2, owner IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT USER)
  RETURN INTEGER IS
  T    VARCHAR2(64) := UPPER(table_name);
  o    VARCHAR2(64) := UPPER(owner);
  expr VARCHAR2(32767);
  q    INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'SELECT /*+FULL(T) PARALLEL(T)*/' || COUNT(*) || ' * COUNT(*) OVER () - ' || listagg('COUNT(' || column_name || ')', ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) || ' FROM ' || o || '.' || T || ' t'
  INTO   expr
  FROM   all_tab_columns
  WHERE  table_name = T;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE expr INTO q;

  RETURN q;
END;
/

-- Usage 1
SELECT null_fields('<your table name>') FROM dual
/

-- Usage 2
SELECT null_fields('<your table name>', '<table owner>') FROM dual
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic SQL you execute (this is the string used in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) should be

```
select sum(
    decode(a,null,1,0)
    +decode(b,null,1,0)
    +decode(c,null,1,0)
    ) nullcols
from test;
```

Where each summand corresponds to a NOT NULL column.

Here only one table scan is necessary to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data dictionary to find the number of `NULL` values almost instantly:

```
select sum(num_nulls) sum_num_nulls
from all_tab_columns
where owner = user
    and table_name = 'TEST';

SUM_NUM_NULLS
-------------
6
```

The values will only be correct if optimizer statistics were gathered recently and if they were gathered with the default value for the sample size.

Those may seem like large caveats but it's worth becoming familiar with your database's statistics gathering process anyway.  If your database is *not* automatically gathering statistics or if your database is *not* using the default sample size those are likely huge problems you need to be aware of.

To manually gather stats for a specific table a statement like this will work:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST');
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select COUNT(1) TOTAL from table where COLUMN is NULL;
```

Comment: COL = NULL does not correct. COL IS NULL really works

Comment: What is `count(1)`? The standard SQL expression is `count(*)`.

Comment: @YenierTorres Thanks for correction COL is NULL it should be(corrected).
Thanks

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It can be anything, I am used to COUNT(1) or COUNT(COL_NAME) all give the correct result. Thanks

Comment: @Gurdyal: `count(*)` and `count(1)` are indeed the same thing. However `count(*)` and `count(col_name)` are **NOT** the same thing

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: it is a very old (and wrong) performance myth that `count(1)` is faster then `count(*)`. Similar as the myth that `where exists (select 1 ...)` is faster then `where exists (select * ..)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please elaborate a little bit why COUNT(*) is NOT same as COUNT(COL_NAME) in this case.
AM I missing something here?

Comment: @Gurdyal: `select count(col_name) from x` is equivalent to `select count(*) from x where col_name IS NOT null`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
are you saying 
1) select count(col_name) from x where col_name IS NOT null
and
2) select count(*) from x where col_name IS NOT null
are NOT the same
I am talking about this case (Original Question)
They are same as far as I can remember (I dont have access to SQL at the moment)
Thanks